# Eclipse tabbing deletes my text

Tags: eclipse

I was coding in eclipse when out of a sudden eclipse began to delete marked text that I wanted to tab. I was looking through all settings but didn't find anything. Is there a shortkey?

Comment: Did you accidentally turn on overwrite mode (down in the status bar next to the row:column display)?

Comment: I can't see anything of it, also not in my settings. http://prntscr.com/1k8efb

Comment: In the status bar, you should see a cell that says "Writable", then another one in the middle, then one that has a row:column indicator. What does the middle cell say?

Comment: It said "writable". Now I've restarted eclipse and voila - it works.